# Call a member function of other Class

Tags: c++

I have 2 classes.

```
Class A
{
  void printMe();
}
```

cpp File:

```
A::printMe(){
   cout<<"yay";
 }

Class B
 {
    void DoSomething();
 }
```

cpp File

```
 B::DoSomething(){

    A::printMe();
 }
```

How do I make an object of Class A in Class B and use it for the function printMe();

References, but the answers are not accepted and they did not work for me 
[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20317224/c-call-member-function-from-other-class)

Comment: Show your real code as fed to the compiler, and any error messages you've got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to call the `printMe()` member function on an object of class A:

```
B::DoSomething() {
  A a;
  a.printMe();
}
```

However you also need to declare the `printMe()` function to be public:

```
class A {
public:
  void printeMe();
}
```

Comment: Error: 'A' was not declared in this scope

Comment: @UmeshMoghariya: You'll need the definition of `class A` before you can create an object or call a member function. If it's in a header file, then include that. If you're just writing a single source file, then make sure `A` comes before `B`. This should all be covered by your introductory book.

Comment: @MikeSeymour yes, I am using a header file and included it in the code.

Comment: I had error due to a different Bug, but the solution holds correct.

Answer (score 1):

First you'll need to correct the many syntax errors:

```
// A.h
class A {    // not Class
public:      // otherwise you can only call the function from A
    void printMe();
};           // missing ;

// B.h
class B {    // not Class
public:      // probably needed
    void DoSomething();
};           // missing ;

// A.cpp
#include "A.h"       // class definition is needed
#include <iostream>  // I/O library is needed (cout)

void A::printMe() {        // missing return type
    std::cout << "yay\n";  // missing namespace qualifier
}

// B.cpp
#include "A.h"       // class definitions are needed
#include "B.h"

void B::DoSomething() {    // missing return type
    A a;                   // make an object of type A
    a.printMe();           // call member function
}
```